# Why True value returns True with membership in function in python

Tags: python

When True is not element of the list, why it returns True?

```
print(True in [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`True` is implictly converted to a number, `1`. (`False` would be converted to `0`) The `in` operator checks if any element is equal to the left operand, and `True` is equal to the first element, `1`.

```py
>>> True == 1
True
```